# Random Crashes On Nextbook Ares 8

Tags: 5.1-lollipop, system-error

I need help. My Nextbook Ares 8 (NXA8QC116 5.1.1 Lollipop) keeps randomly crashing when I am on it, although when it is plugged in, it doesn't crash. HELP PLEASE!

NOTE: Now it does crash when it's plugged in.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by randomly crashing? please explain the crashing

Comment: I mean that after a while of it being on, it turns off unexpectedly even though it's not dead.

Comment: May be your battery is dead as this doesn't happen when it is plugged in.

Comment: When I turn it back on, it still has charge. So that can't be the problem.

Comment: Did you try resetting it? (you'll lose your data though)

Comment: I refuse to reset it. Although, maybe downgrading it to 5.0 might work. Do you think it might work?

Comment: I don't think so since the problem may be on hardware side... Or try clearing the cache. But I'd recommend you reset it. Just backup your data.